# Nextcord is there a way to make a cog but make it disabled by default

Tags: nextcord

Basically I'm trying to make a cog where I added some pranks but I want to make it disabled(unloaded) by default is there any way to do that?

Comment: Cogs are not added to the bot by default, you can use `bot.add_cog()` to add it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change the cog's name to something like:

_cogname.py

And when you load your cogs, do the following:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py') and not filename.startswith('_'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Make sure you do:
`import os`
at the start of your code